# Comparing characters in two different string

Tags: python-3.x

Given a sample word chain which looks like

```
host
must
most
post
cost
cast
east
vast
fast
easy
ease
case
```

I need to determine each sequential word is differred by only one letter.
For e.g. the following is a valid word-chain, consisting of exactly 3 words where each word differs from previous word by exactly one letter.

```
Shop
Stop
Step
```

I need to write a program which return true if the condition is met, otherwise it prints **Invalid step from (word1) to (word2)**

So far I tried putting those words into a list and then stripping their characters into a list of list and compare them. But its neither efficient nor correct way.
Any suggestions for this?

My code:

```
seen=['poll','roll','toll','told']

alist=[]
for i in seen:
    chain1=[]
    for j in i:
        chain1.append(j)
    alist.append(chain1)
for i in range(len(alist)-1):
    for j in range(len(alist)-1):
        chars=[]
        if alist[i][j] not in alist[i+1][j]:
            chars.append(alist[i+1][j])
            if len(chars)>1:
                print('Invalid step from', alist[i], '->', alist[i + 1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
seen=['poll','roll','toll','told']

def check(x,y):
  cnt = 0
  for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] != y[i]:
      cnt += 1
  return cnt

for i in range(len(seen)-1):
  if(1 != check(seen[i],seen[i+1])):
    print('Invalid step from', seen[i], '->', seen[i + 1])
    break
```

First define a function that checks the character at each position to see how different the two strings are. If exactly one character differs, we are good. Otherwise, we stop checking further because the word ladder is invalid.

Note that the above logic assumes that each string in your input is of the same length, and also that you are not jumbling up the word in changing the letter i.e. 'roll' to 'plol' is not a valid transition even though only one character has changed

Comment: Sir, what if  not just the first word is changed and maybe some other word is changed? Like in the sample list I provided at the start of the question, there's an invalid step from host to must. Is there any changes we can do in the check function to include such cases, too?

Comment: The check function takes any two strings as input and does the comparison. It is up to your calling code to decide which strings get passed to it. In my sample, we compare the first string in the list to the second, then second to third, and so on, but of course that can be changed

Comment: I got that. What I wanted to ask was, in that function we were only concerened about the first letter of the string. What if some other letters are changed? How do we inlcude such cases.

For e.g. if we see the seen list. It prints 'Invalid step from toll -> told' which is wrong. Because it is a right step since only one letter is changed. So how do we fix this?

Comment: OK, I think I understand. My return was indented wrong, so it did not return what I was expecting, I have fixed it now

Comment: Okay, lets see for the list seen=seen=['poll','roll','toll','told'], step from 'toll' to 'told' is perfectly fine since only one letter is changed from 'toll' to get 'told'. But when I srun the check(x,y) function on it, It shows **Invalid step from toll -> told**

Comment: Please try with the latest code. The indentation issue is fixed and returns the expected result now

Comment: Thanks for catching the error, do remember to mark the answer as accepted if it helped